# How to determine the request type in Rack middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, middleware

I have the following Rack middleware to detect old versions of internet explorer:

```
require 'user_agent'

module Rack
  class IERedirect

    def initialize(app, url)
      @app = app
      @redirect_url = url
    end

    def call(env)
      request = Rack::Request.new(env)
      useragent = UserAgent.new(env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].to_s)
      path = env["PATH_INFO"]
      if (useragent.name == :ie && (useragent.version.to_i < 10))
        [ 302, {'Location'=> "#{@redirect_url}" }, [] ]
      else
        @app.call(env)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What I would like to do is add another condition to the if statement which is to allow all POST requests. Is this possible in the middleware?

Answer (score 3):

There's a method in the Rack::Request object: `request.post?`
there are also `.get?` `.patch?` `.put?`, etc.